# How to get Menu Navigation Labels to output HTML

Tags: menus, navigation, icon

I'm trying to follow [Jason Bradley's advice](http://jasonbradley.me/icons-in-the-wordpress-menu/) on how to style my Wordpress menus.

Specifically, I want to insert an icon before my navigation items using [Font-Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/examples/#navigation).

I tried putting this code in the Navigation Label field for my "Home" link:

```
<i class="icon-fixed-width icon-home"></i> Home
```

However, when I view the page in my browser, it displays the HTML verbatim, it doesn't interpret the  tag, or any other HTML I throw at it, for that matter.

Did Wordpress Menus change in 3.6? Am I missing something obvious?

I know that my font-awesome installation works because I am using their icons all over my site. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Navigation" field is *not* where you want to place your CSS class. The navigation is what the user will see in the menu, so don't put any code there.

To enter a custom CSS class to your item, you need to do the following:

- Click the "Screen Options" tab in the top right corner of the page.
- Under "Show advanced menu properties", tick the "CSS Classes" checkbox.
- Now for every menu item, you have a field labelled "CSS Classes (optional)" where you can enter "icon-fixed-width icon-home".

Job done! :)

Comment: I knew about that already, but thanks for the suggestion. I always have that to fall back on in case this doesn't work. According to his tutorial he's putting the <i> tag directly in the Navigation Fields: http://jasonbradley.me/icons-in-the-wordpress-menu/#comment-742

Comment: I'd agree and advise against isnerting html markup, if you really must have an element to style, use :after and :before css selectors

Comment: I just gave it a try. In my case, inserting the <i class="icon-fixed-width icon-home"></i> into the Title field of my menu item does work: the markup is hidden on the frontend. But the method of just using the "CSS Classes" field also works with Font Awesome, and seems a much cleaner way.

Comment: My menu items had HTML in them but since updating WP to 3.9.2 re-saving the menu results in the label's **HTML being stripped**. Use the class field rather.

Comment: This is not answer JP question. He wants to insert HTML on menu label.

Comment: Yep, he asked for HTML... but based on the code he provided, the point was actually to add the "icon-fixed-width icon-home" classes. The <i> html element is presentational, not semantic. Therefore, it seems a better solution to add CSS classes.

Answer (score 1):

Get custom navigation title using page id:

```
function get_custom_nav_title( $menu_name, $page_id ) { 
    $args = array(
        'order'                  => 'ASC',
        'orderby'                => 'menu_order',
        'post_type'              => 'nav_menu_item',
        'post_status'            => 'publish',
        'output'                 => ARRAY_A,
        'output_key'             => 'menu_order',
        'nopaging'               => true,
        'update_post_term_cache' => false 
    );
    $items = wp_get_nav_menu_items( $menu_name, $args );
    //print_r( $items );
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        if ( $item->object_id == $page_id ) {
            return $item->title;
        }
    }   
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation. Explain why your code should work. Also please format your code.